# Confusion calculating steady-state error in MATLAB

Tags: control, control-system, matlab

I am trying to use MATLAB to calculate a steady-state error.
I have found a [weblink](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/4375-steady-state-error-command) that gives code for finding the steady-state error, but when I use that code I get a value of the steady-error greater than 1. In my understanding, a steady-state error should be less than 1, because formula of steady-state error in case of step input = 1/(1+k)

The code:

`sserror=abs(SP-y(end))`

When I try to incorporate the above code into my code to get the steady-state error:

```
clc;clear all;close all
%defining parameters values
Ra=1
Kt=10
Kb=0.1
j=2
b=0.5
%defining numerator & denominator of system1 (1/js+b)
num=[1]
den=[j b]
% creating transfer function for system 1
sys1=tf(num,den)
%Applying block diagram reduction and simplification techniques
sys2=(-Kb)*Kt/Ra
%Creating a positive feedback system from above two systems sys1 and sys2
a=feedback(sys1,sys2,1)
%Introducing the effect of disturbance input 
OL=-1*a
%Calculating step response & extracting amplitude & time matrices
[y,t]=step(OL)
%Plotting  values of amplitude matrix extracted from  step resposne
plot(y)
%Calculating length(total number of elements) for timing matrix 
z=length(t)
%Finding value of last element of amplitude matrix
%That is also value of steady state speed
open_loop_steady_state_speed=y(z)
SP=1 % set point incase of step input
sserror=abs(SP-y(end))
```

I am trying to simulate a block diagram from a book, *Modern Control Systems*. I am also attaching a snapshot of that block diagram.

There are two block diagrams in the snapshot, one is for an open-loop control system and the other is for a closed-loop control system.

I am considering and trying to write code for an open-loop system.

**Update: Note: Plot has been added in response to comment**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post a time versus value plot of the signal?

Comment: If the set point is **positive**, then clearly the steady state error is more than one since the response is **negative** value.

Comment: Good day. I don't have an answer to the question but wanted to ask the name/title of the book where are figures 4.7 and 4.9 from. Could you say, please?

Comment: @Agasha - Hi, I didn't write the question, but I believe I recognise the figures as being from the book "Modern Control Systems" by Richard C. Dorf and Robert H. Bishop. Hopefully *LECS* can confirm that.

Answer (score 1):

```matlab
a=feedback(sys1,sys2,1)

OL=-1*a

[y,t]=step(OL)
```

The output of the closed loop system is **negated** before it is supplied to the step function.

So even though the output of the original system `a` is going to `0.66` (steady state error `0.33`), due to the negation of the output in `OL`, the calculation returns `1.66 > 1`.

What is the reason / logic for doing `OL = -1 * a` ?

### Note

There is one logical error also.

```matlab
[y,t]=step(OL)         % SP is NOT the input given here!
SP=1                   % the set point has NO effect on y !
sserror=abs(SP-y(end)) % this calculation is hence invalid
```

Since the step function is called **before** setting the setpoint `SP`, the calculation `SP - y(end)` is invalid since `SP` was **not** the input actually supplied to the system.

The code in the link you provided in the question has the correct order of operations.

```matlab
SP=5; %input value, if you put 1 then is the same as step(sys)
[y,t]=step(SP*sys); %get the response of the system to a step with amplitude SP
sserror=abs(SP-y(end)) %get the steady state error
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I think you should be treating at the system like this, and analyze the system this way, taking \$T_d(s)\$ as your main input. With such a diagram, the definition for sys2 and sys1 changes, as you might notice. It becomes the formula below.

$$sys2=\frac{K_m(K_tK_b+K_a)}{R_a}$$
$$sys1=\frac{-1}{Js+b}$$

Rewriting the code according to this might yield a correct result.